# Determine where the driver information is stored for odbc

Tags: r

I got my connection from R to a MS SQL Server database working on a Mac.  I was able to get the right driver for the connection string by issuing the `odbcListDrivers()` command.  However, I don't know if it was there or not before I started installing things like `freetds` and `brew install --no-sandbox msodbcsql17 mssql-tools`.

What I'd like to know is: with the `odbcListDrivers()`, how do I know what the file is it pulls from (a `.ini` one, I'm thinking)?  I struggled because the configuration files I configured for freetds and another odbc.ini file don't affect what R is reading I believe, and made troubleshooting difficult.

In case I need to configure more drivers or DSN (?) entries.